# DPDK - interrupts rather than polling

Tags: dpdk

Is it possible to configure DPDK so that the NIC sends an interrupt whenever a packet is received (rather than turning off interrupts and having the core poll on the RX queue)? I know this seems counterintuitive but there is a use case I have in mind that could benefit from this.

DPDK claims to allow you to use interrupts for RX queues (you can call `rte_eth_dev_rx_intr_enable` and pass a port/queue pair as arguments), but upon digging through the code, it seems that this is misleading. There is a polling thread that calls `epoll_wait`, and upon receipt of a packet, calls `eal_intr_process_interrupts`. This function then goes through a list of callback functions (which are supposed to be the interrupt handlers) and executes each one. The function then calls `epoll_wait` again (i.e. it is in an infinite loop).

Is my understanding of how DPDK handles "interrupts" correct? In other words, even if you turn "interrupts" on, DPDK is really just polling in the background and then executing callback functions (so there are no interrupts)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my understanding of how DPDK handles "interrupts" correct?

DPDK is a user space application. Unfortunately, there is no magic way to receive an interrupt callback directly to the user space application.

So NIC interrupts get serviced in kernel any way, then kernel notifies to a user space using an `eventfd`. User space thread waits for the `eventfd` notification using `epoll_wait`.

> In other words, even if you turn "interrupts" on, DPDK is really just polling in the background and then executing callback functions (so there are no interrupts)?

If there is no data to receive, DPDK polling thread should block on `epoll_wait`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was expecting. Thanks for your help. Just to clarify, it seems that when you turn interrupts on, the NIC does send actual interrupts, but these are received in the kernel (so you would need to inject a signal into the app). Ahhh I wish they had userspace interrupts.

Comment: The eventfd mechanism is fast and easy to use. If it's not fast enough, we can always hack the kernel module and change it to whatever suits our needs... It's open source ;)